# Open a new window from a button?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

i want to open a new window from a button, but in this new window I retrieve an address from my servlet (Action)

```
<html:button property="bouton" styleId="bouton" styleClass="boutonYellow" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 38, 97); width:200px;cursor:default;"  disabled="true">
<fmt:message key="name"/>
</html:button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
onclick="window.open(${url})"
```

The URL (being a request attribute in the above code) can contain GET parameters that you can use in the new page. Or it can be a servlet URL where you process the parameters and forward/redirect to a view (page).

Comment: thx, but in this new page I need to recover some data from my servlet

Comment: what stops you from doing it?

Comment: I do not know how to call my servlet, retrieve my information and open new window?

Comment: The URL can be one of a servlet, redirecting to a page.